# What causes a post to be auto-flagged for many edits more than once?

Tags: support, edits, flags, moderator-tools

Now that [automatic community wiki is finally dead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227290/stop-using-community-wiki-as-a-reputation-denial-mechanism), when a post is edited too many times and/or by too many users, the post is automatically flagged for moderator review.

I just reviewed a post that received one such flag. The edit that triggered the flag was revoked within the grace period. There was something else that needed editing so I made that edit, and in doing so I triggered the flag a second time.

Is this because the previous edit was revoked, making it not count toward the auto-flag threshold? Are there any other situations in which these new auto-flags could be raised more than once in the lifetime of a post?

Answer (score 11):

The rules for the new flags are, in intention:

- Flags for multiple edits, be it by the original author or by multiple authors, should only happen once in the lifetime of the post.
- Flags for a post hitting a certain number of answers *total* should only happen once in the lifetime of the post.
- Flags for a post hitting a certain number of answers *within 7 days*, can happen more than once. However, this flag will not be raised if it hasn't been at least 7 days from when the flag was last raised.

---

There was a bug that the check to prevent future flags only looked for live flags. As such, once a flag was cleared, any future revision would then check to see if the author had edited the post more than 10 times, and on noticing it was true, it would re-assert the flag. Jarrod has pushed out a fix to resolve this.

This still means that anything old which has had 10+ edits from the original author in the past, a new edit will cause it to be flagged if it has not yet been flagged since the system was in place. To reduce this from being a bad flood, we've opted to ignore community wiki posts when making this check - this should restrict it so that your attention is only brought to non-wiki posts, where it's more likely that the high edit count *may* be an issue.

These two changes will go out in the next build, with thanks to Jarrod for being able to come quickly for the fix.

Comment: Even more curious then: I've seen more than a few posts by now that have been flagged more than once in their lifetime. There are some pending right now that I've left in the queue for you to look at.

Comment: @Boltclock Let's make that "some time" a lot sooner then. I found one particular case that shouldn't have risen flags for half the instances that it did, even if we flagged for each edit past the tenth.

Comment: @BoltClock I cleaned those flags up - totally my bug.