# Show Edits Remaining

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki

As far as I understand, you can edit a post **10** times before it becomes a wiki.

Would it be beneficial to display the remaining edits to the user?

Maybe something like this:

[image: Idea 1]

Or maybe on the "edit revisions" page:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> you can edit a post 10 times before it becomes a wiki

[Not anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228940/152859):

> I'm happy to announce that we have removed all of the automatic triggers that convert a post to community wiki.

So, [status-irrelevant](/questions/tagged/status-irrelevant) :)

Comment: Thanks for correcting!

Comment: Sure, also fixed Grace's incorrect answer.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  This is only my second post on meta, since my question was based on false assumptions, should I just delete it?  Or give you the answer?

Comment: @Tyler your call, you can't delete it yourself but if you feel it's not useful to others you can flag your question choose Other and ask to delete. :)

Answer (score 0):

That wouldn't be particularly helpful, no.  The wikification or nonwikification of a question should not have any relation to whether an edit should or should not be done.  If a question needs to be improved, it should be improved, and if that means it becomes CW, so be it.  Converting to community wiki isn't a punishment; it's simply acknowledging that a question has had many changes and should be considered more of a collaboration than a single user's work.

Comment: Before it was removed, this restriction was only for the poster of the question or answer, so I'm not sure whether this relates to the point here.