# How to ask community wiki question?

Tags: support, community-wiki

> Note: I have flagged this post to be changed to a community wiki because I'm unable to do so.

I have a few C# interview questions I genuinely wanted to give to our community. I was looking for option to make the question community wiki however I didn't found one.

Can an option be provided to make a new question community wiki?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make questions community wiki anymore, this ability is restricted to diamond moderators now. The community wiki feature on SE is not exactly intuitive, often misunderstood and was mostly used in ways it wasn't actually intended to work.

There is no good reason to make a question community wiki at all on mosts sites now. Questions are generally not collaboratively edited, so the wiki part isn't useful. And the reputation denial only discourages users from answering as they won't get any reputation for it.

Community wiki also isn't an excuse to post otherwise off-topic questions, simply because you don't earn reputation for them. Either questions are on-topic, and everyone should earn reputation for them, or they're not and shouldn't be posted at all.

Comment: yes, I got it. I simply wanted to share the interview problems. Also flagged it to moderators. My task is done :)

Comment: I was not aware that "You can't make questions community wiki anymore, this ability is restricted to diamond moderators now." - I'm assuming that perspective comes from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227290/stop-using-community-wiki-as-a-reputation-denial-mechanism but http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/ says "An author can still apply the status manually when posting or when editing their own answer" - is it just questions that authors cannot make CW now?

Comment: @PolyGeo Yes, for answers this still works. I think it requires a minimum reputation, but not much. CW for answers still makes sense, CW for questions never really made much sense to begin with.

Comment: @student those "interview problems" are off topic here, and just noise. I removed them from your post.