# Regarding automatic conversion of community wikis

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I found that there were some events that automatically convert questions/answers to community wikis (see [Stop using community wiki as a reputation denial mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227290/stop-using-community-wiki-as-a-reputation-denial-mechanism)). 
For example,

1. Automatic conversion after 10 edits
2. Automatic conversion after 30 answers
3. Automatic conversion after 5 users edited the
   post

I am locating into answers of community wiki questions and their edit histories to understand whether I can identify those triggers.

However, I found some challenges.
So, to identify whether 30'th answer automatically triggers the community wiki conversion, I match the time and user id of the 30th answer with the time and user id of community wiki conversion event in the PostHistory table (PostHistotyTypeId=16). Interestingly, sometimes I found the match at 27, 28 or 29'th answer. I even found the match at the 8th answer. (see this community wiki questions and the 8th answer in time: [Android error: Failed to install *.apk on device *: timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout)).
Similarly, for the edits (I consider PostHistoryTypeId=4,5,6 for counting edits). I found that conversion occurs at 11'th edit.
See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2371292/revisions
Here, OP N1.1 performs more than 10 edits but the community wiki has been attributed to a different user (a diamond moderator).

This warns me that I am possibly missing something important. What is the proper way of detecting which answer or edit triggers automatic conversion? If the process I am following is correct, why I am finding triggers at a different position?

Comment: You're not accounting for the possibility of a bunch of deleted answers existing on the question. Also, you do realize that we no longer automatically convert to community wiki, ever, right?

Comment: Thanks. I understand that automatic conversions are no longer available for posts. I agree that there can be deleted answers. How about the edit example I provided for post: 2371292. What can be a possible explanation?

Comment: You'll notice all those statements say *after* (so greater than). The actual conversion took place at the 11th edit or the 31st answer. Fwiw, we *used* to show the reason alongside the revision history item. I believe at some point that code was just completely removed due to automatic conversion no longer being a thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That explains much. So, out of the 11 edits made by N1.1, one was a rollback. So, N1.1 already performed 10 edits. Just, after that George Stocker♦ performed the edit. At this point, the post became a community wiki. The wiki conversion entry attributed to George Stocker♦.

Comment: No longer automatically convert to community wiki - *["2014-04-09: Former criteria for the automatic conversion of community wiki have been removed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/214543#214543)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen I am aware of that. We are doing a study about the community wiki. I am interested in finding those trigger points from the data.