# When does a post return to the top?

Tags: support, bump, posting

When does an old post return to the top of the question list? It seems to involve re-editing AND a window of time, i.e., if the edit is much later than the original post, it wouldn't move back to the top, right?

Comment: The act of "old post return to the top of the question stack" is called "bumping", there is whole faq about it. It's not only editing, so your answer is misleading, though not wrong. (As one might assume only editing would bump)

Comment: It shouldn't [be abused](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227290/stop-using-community-wiki-as-a-reputation-denial-mechanism/228940#228940) - *"Edits by the original author, edits by other people, and even volume of answers, all of these no longer cause a post to be automatically converted to community wiki. There will instead be flags for moderator action cast in these situations"*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the active tab up - any edit (to the question or answers to it ), bounty or new  answer would bump up the post. Unanswered questions are also periodically bumped up for attention automatically.

There's generally a short delay due to when the page loads as well as caching.

Comment: yes, re-editing will move the post back to the top, but there is a delay (not a split-second...)